# Error when trying to add a student to database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, data-access-layer

I get an error when I'm trying to add a student with one attribute, name. 
The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name')' at line 1.

The error points out this codes,

```
 //Class DAL
    public int addStudent(String name)throws SQLException{

        PreparedStatement studentStatement = getConnected().prepareStatement("insert       into person" + "values (?)") ;
        studentStatement.setString(1,name);
             //This is highlighted by the error
        int rSetStudent = studentStatement.executeUpdate();
        return rSetStudent;
    }

 //Class controller

public int addStudent(String name) throws SQLException{
          //This is highlighted
    return dal.addStudent(name);
}

//and this in class MainFrame where i use the add method from controller class
//this is highlighted
private void addStudent(){
    try{
                 //and this
        int a = controller.addStudent(nameTxtField.getText().trim());
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The method `addStudent()` is called when the button *add* is clicked. 
If somebody wonders I'm using MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this line `PreparedStatement studentStatement = getConnected().prepareStatement("insert       into person" + "values (?)"`) there is no space between person and values

do like this

`PreparedStatement studentStatement = getConnected().prepareStatement("insert       into person " + "values (?)"`) or simply

`PreparedStatement studentStatement = getConnected().prepareStatement("insert       into person values (?)"`) for no confusion about spaces

Comment: This worked too and it looks more correctly. I'll mark this as an answer too.

Comment: @Eskipo I would suggest you to use the 2nd way

Comment: "i"+" "+"would"+" "+"choose"+" "+"the"+" "+second"+" "+"way"+" :D"

Comment: @JqueryLearner "okay" + "I'll go"+ "with it" :D

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
insert into person (name) values (?)
```

Comment: Wow that fixed it thanks a lot. I'll accept this as an answer.